# When adding column to view, how do I specify datatype?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a task to be completed using Oracle SQL where I want to create a simple dataview that is ultimately going to be joined from a different view. However, in order to properly join the two views, I first need to add a column specifying that for each row in this view, it is a 'Flare'. I have completed that, but the challenge is that the data is a char(5) datatype, and I want to change it to a varchar2(4000) datatype. Any help or pointing me in the right direction would be much appreciated.

```
create or replace view Q_FLARES as
   select 
      t.*,
      (case
         when t.FACILITY_ID is not null then 'Flare' --<---<-- Need this to be varchar2(4000)
      end) as UNITTYPE
   from
   (select
      FACILITY_ID,
      REPORTING_YEAR,
      FACILITY_NAME,
      sum(CO2emmval) as CO2
   from
      flaregasUnit
   ) t;
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe you just need an explicit conversion using [`CAST`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions016.htm).

```
create or replace view Q_FLARES as
   select 
      t.*,
      CAST
      (
        (
         case
         when t.FACILITY_ID is not null then 'Flare' --<- Need this to be varchar2(4000)
         end
        ) AS varchar2(4000) 
      ) as UNITTYPE
   from
   (select
      FACILITY_ID,
      REPORTING_YEAR,
      FACILITY_NAME,
      sum(CO2emmval) as CO2
   from
      flaregasUnit
   ) t;
```